# UpdateView - Update a class that has OneToOne with User

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Say I have a model called `MyUser`. It has some field, and one of them is this one:

> user = OneToOneField(User, related_name='more_user_information')

I want to make a view to update this model, and I do the following:

```
Class AccountEdit(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = MyUser
    form_class = MyUserForm
    template_name = 'accounts/edit.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.model.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

Each field in `MyUser` renders fine for editing, except `user`. This one to one field becomse a select drop down box. What I like to do is to edit the fields on `User` model like first name or last name.

How can I achieve this while extending `UpdateView`? or perhaps shuold I use a `FormView`?

thanks

Comment: class based views suck!

Comment: No, they don't :) if you know to use them

Comment: i know how to use them, but it makes things unnecessarily complex

Comment: then tell me how to use this one :P

Comment: but itsnot about class-based views here though. you could render two separate modelforms and process them inside one ``<form>``, couldnot you?

Answer (score 3):

This problem is actually nothing to do with class based views or update view - its a basic issue that has been there since the beginning, which is:

> ModelForms only edit the fields for one model, and don't recurse into
>   foreign keys.

In other words, if you have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   a = models.ForeignKey('Foo')
   b = models.ForeignKey('Bar')
   c = models.ForeignKey('Zoo')
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

A model form will render three select fields, one for each foreign key, and these select fields will have all the values from those models listed - along with one text field for the name.

To solve this problem, you need to use [`InlineFormSets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets):

> Inline formsets is a small abstraction layer on top of model formsets.
>   These simplify the case of working with related objects via a foreign
>   key.

You should use [`InlineFormSet`](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) from the excellent `django-extra-views` app. To do this, you'll create a view for the related object as well:

```
class MyUserInline(InlineFormSet):
    model = MyUser

    def get_object(self):
        return MyUser.objects.get(user=self.request.user)


class AccountEditView(UpdateWithInlinesView):
    model = User
    inlines = [MyUserInline]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [django-betterforms](https://github.com/fusionbox/django-betterforms)'s [Multiform and ModelMultiForm](http://django-betterforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/multiform.html).

Example:

```
class UserProfileMultiForm(MultiForm):
    form_classes = {
        'user': UserForm,
        'profile': ProfileForm,
    }
```

It works with generic CBV (CreateView, UpdateView, WizardView).